# Filtering Ember.js data in template based on boolean

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-data, javascript-framework

I’m currently building a photo approval app on Ember.js. Photos in the model have a default of `approved = true`. Within the app, clicking a photo toggles this state, so they can be blacklisted quickly.

I want to set up some routes that filter and show `approved = true`, `approved = false` and `all` photos.

My `router.js`:

```
App.Router.map ->
  @resource "photos", ->
    @resource "photo",
      path: ":photo_id"
    # additional child routes
    @route "approved"
    @route "disapproved"\
```

My `photo.js` model:

```
App.Photo = DS.Model.extend(
  name: DS.attr("string")
  description: DS.attr("string")
  image_url: DS.attr("string")
  approved: DS.attr("boolean")
)
```

Here is where the problem code lies, in my `photos_route.js`:

```
App.PhotosRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
  model: ->
    App.Photo.find()
)

App.PhotosApprovedRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
  model: ->
    @store.filter "photo", (photo) ->
      photo.get("approved")

  renderTemplate: (controller) ->
    @render "photos",
      controller: controller
)

App.PhotosDisapprovedRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
  model: ->
    @store.filter "photo", (photo) ->
      not photo.get("approved")
  renderTemplate: (controller) ->
    @render "photos",
      controller: controller
)
```

And finally, here is how I’m displaying things in the `templates`:

```
{{!-- application.hbs --}}
<header id="header">
  <h2>{{#link-to "index"}}Home{{/link-to}}</h2>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>{{#link-to "photos"}}All photos{{/link-to}}</li>
      <li>{{#link-to "photos.approved"}}Approved{{/link-to}}</li>
      <li>{{#link-to "photos.disapproved"}}Disapproved{{/link-to}}</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<div id="content">
  {{outlet}}
</div>

{{!-- photos.hbs --}}
<h1>Photos</h1>
<ul>
  {{#each controller}}
    <li class="masonry-brick">
      <h3>Approved: {{approved}}</h3>
      {{input type="checkbox" checked=photoApproved class="toggle"}}
      {{#link-to "photo" this}}{{name}}{{/link-to}}
      <img {{bind-attr src=image_url}} alt="Logo">
    </li>
  {{else}}
    <li>There are no photos.</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>

{{outlet}}
```

How would I re-adjust my `photos_routes.js` to get the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [filter function](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_filter) on Store takes two arguments, a query, that is used by the adapter to filter server side and a function to keep the filter live for new or modified object (update stuff in memory). The function signature you're using looks more like the one you use for an Array.

Have a look at the documentation:
http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_filter

An untested version of the routes:

```
App.PhotosApprovedRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
  model: ->
    @store.filter "photo", {approved: true}, (photo) ->
      photo.get("approved")
)

App.PhotosDisapprovedRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
  model: ->
    @store.filter "photo", {approved: false}, (photo) ->
      not photo.get("approved")
)
```

PS. It seems a bit redundant to me. I think the third parameter (predicate) could be inferred by the query... but that's how I understand how it's now according to the docs.

Comment: Great, thanks. This is working all apart from the API request: `http://localhost:3000/api/hotos?approved=true` — it seems to be chopping off the `p` from `photos`, yet there is no trace of `'hotos'` in any of my code. Would it be better practice to make the route `photos?disapproved` instead of `photos/disapproved`?

Comment: I would go with `photos/disapporved`, but I guess that's more of a personal taste/preference and each team has different guidelines. It's not a big either way. In general I would use query strings to filter the same content. However a different URL makes sense if the user thinks of it as separate content, which I think that's the case here.

Comment: Seem to have another issue; I’m getting a `TypeError: Object Photo has no method 'eachRelatedType'` in console.

Comment: Seems like a separate issue, can you post another question or give me more details about it?

Comment: Sure, here’s the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22051678/ember-js-error-object-photo-has-no-method-eachrelatedtype