# Ember.js error: Object Photo has no method 'eachRelatedType'

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js, ember-data

I’m trying to create some routes that filter out approved and disapproved photos from my model (based on a boolean value).

Here’s my main `photos`, `approved` and `disapproved` routes:

```
# router.js
App.Router.map ->
  @resource "photos", ->
    @resource "photo",
      path: ":photo_id"
    # additional child routes
    @route "approved"
    @route "disapproved"

# photos_routes.js
App.PhotosRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
  model: ->
    App.Photo.find()
)

App.PhotosApprovedRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
  model: ->
    @store.filter "Photo", {approved: true}, (photo) ->
      photo.get("approved")
  renderTemplate: ->
    @render "photos"
    @render controller: "PhotosController"
)

App.PhotosDisapprovedRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
  model: ->
    @store.filter "Photo", {approved: false}, (photo) ->
      not photo.get("approved")
  renderTemplate: ->
    @render "photos"
    @render controller: "PhotosController"
)
```

Here’s my `photo.js` model:

```
App.Photo = DS.Model.extend(
  name: DS.attr("string")
  description: DS.attr("string")
  image_url: DS.attr("string")
  approved: DS.attr("boolean")
)
```

And finally, my `application.hbs` and `photos.hbs` templates:

```
{{!-- application.hbs --}}
<header id="header">
  <h2>{{#link-to "index"}}Home{{/link-to}}</h2>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>{{#link-to "photos"}}All photos{{/link-to}}</li>
      <li>{{#link-to "photos.approved"}}Approved{{/link-to}}</li>
      <li>{{#link-to "photos.disapproved"}}Disapproved{{/link-to}}</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<div id="content">
  {{outlet}}
</div>

{{!-- photos.hbs --}}
<h1>Photos</h1>

<ul>
  {{#each controller}}
    <li class="masonry-brick">
      <img {{bind-attr src=image_url}} alt="Logo">
    </li>
  {{else}}
    <li>There are no photos.</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>

{{outlet}}
```

When I click the link-to on either the `photos.approved` or `photos.disapproved`, I get the following errors in console:

```
TypeError: Object Photo has no method 'eachRelatedType'
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: TypeError: Object Photo has no method 'eachRelatedType'
```

Full stack trace:

```
TypeError: Object Photo has no method 'eachRelatedType'
    at DS.JSONSerializer.DS.Serializer.extend.configureSideloadMappingForType (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:7798:10)
    at DS.JSONSerializer.DS.Serializer.extend.sideload (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:7768:10)
    at DS.JSONSerializer.DS.Serializer.extend.extractMany (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:7692:10)
    at superWrapper [as extractMany] (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:1240:16)
    at DS.Adapter.Ember.Object.extend.didFindQuery (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:8329:29)
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:9912:15
    at invokeCallback (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:9754:19)
    at publish (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:9424:9)
    at Promise.publishFulfillment (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:9844:7)
    at Object.DeferredActionQueues.flush (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:5894:24)
    at Object.Backburner.end (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:5985:27) ember.js?body=1:3462
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: TypeError: Object Photo has no method 'eachRelatedType' ember.js?body=1:74
Ember.assert ember.js?body=1:74
Ember.RSVP.onerrorDefault ember.js?body=1:16899
__exports__.default.trigger ember.js?body=1:8718
Promise._onerror ember.js?body=1:9442
publishRejection ember.js?body=1:9849
DeferredActionQueues.flush ember.js?body=1:5894
Backburner.end ember.js?body=1:5985
Backburner.run ember.js?body=1:6024
Ember.run ember.js?body=1:6427
hash.success ember-data.js?body=1:10004
fire jquery.js?body=1:3049
self.fireWith jquery.js?body=1:3161
done jquery.js?body=1:8236
callback
```

Comment: Can you share the network request response body? Seems like the problem is with the data that you're receiving

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I shouldn't answer in comments. Your stack trace happens in your custom serializer. You should probably post that code, as that's where the error lies.

But given the error, and the fact that `eachRelatedType` is a static method, not an instance method, it's likely that you're calling it on an instance. Instead of `photo.eachRelatedType()`, call `photo.constructor.eachRelatedType()` or `App.Photo.eachRelatedType()`.

EDIT: It seems you don't have a custom serializer. But Ember-Data never calls `eachRelatedType`, it only defines it. What version of Ember-Data are you using?

EDIT2: It seems that this particular issue was solved by upgrading from Ember-Data 0.14. Although no exact cause for it is known. (Could have been an Ember-Data bug.)

Comment: Yes, it’s a strange one as any searches for this error don’t return anything relevant. My ember-data is `version: v0.14`

Comment: That would be why. `0.14` is pretty old (6 months). Any chance you can upgrade to the latest beta? If not, I think you're going to have to reproduce this is a JSBin for us to really help. I'm pretty familiar with the inner working of Ember-Data, but not any versions that old.

Comment: Ah that was one of the problems. I’ve now upgraded and hard refreshed, but the `/approved` and `/disapproved` routes now show all photos. Is this something to do with my `renderTemplate` function above?

Comment: I think it does have to do with your render function. You call render twice, giving the controller the second time. Maybe try using the function in the form listed here: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_render

Comment: I’ve marked this one as complete, as we resolved the original issue. Going to post up this new issue on a separate question and will link to it here. Would be great if you could take a quick look.

Comment: I’ve tried hacking away with the new problem, but am running into some route issues with the main application outlet. New question for it is up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22079131/ember-js-child-route-conflicts-with-main-application-outlet.