# Ember.js child route conflicts with main application outlet

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js, ember-data

I’m trying to set up my template so it displays `approved`, `disapproved` and `all` photos, based off a boolean in my model. These routes all use the same main outlet in the `application.hbs` file (referenced below).

These routes are working all fine, except when I go from `photos` → `approved/disapproved` → `photos`. In other words, when returning back to `photos` from either `approved` or `disapproved`, the outlet is blank (with no console errors). Refreshing the page brings it back again.

Here’s how my `router.js` is set up:

```
App.Router.map ->
  @resource "photos", path: "/", ->
    # additional child routes
    @route "approved"
    @route "disapproved"
    @resource "photo",
      path: ":photo_id"
```

The `photos_routes.js`:

```
App.PhotosRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
  model: ->
    @store.find 'photo'
)

App.PhotosApprovedRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
  model: ->
    @store.filter 'photo', approved: true, (photo) ->
      photo.get 'approved'
  renderTemplate: (controller) ->
    @render 'photos',
      into: 'application'
      controller: controller
)

App.PhotosDisapprovedRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
  model: ->
    @store.filter 'photo', approved: false, (photo) ->
      not photo.get 'approved'
  renderTemplate: (controller) ->
    @render 'photos',
      into: 'application'
      controller: controller
)
```

The `application.hbs` and `photos.hbs`

```
{{!-- application.hbs --}}

<ul>
  <li>{{#link-to "photos" activeClass="selected"}}All photos{{/link-to}}</li>
  <li>{{#link-to "photos.approved" activeClass="selected"}}Approved{{/link-to}}</li>
  <li>{{#link-to "photos.disapproved" activeClass="selected"}}Disapproved{{/link-to}}</li>
</ul>

{{outlet}}

{{!-- photos.hbs --}}

<ul>
  {{#each controller}}
    <li {{bind-attr class=":masonry-brick approved:photo__approved:photo__disapproved"}}>
      {{input type="checkbox" checked=approved class="toggle"}}
      <img {{bind-attr src=image_url}} alt="Logo">
    </li>
  {{else}}
    <li>There are no photos.</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Another issue is that the `activeClass` on the 'All photos' navigation link remains active on all other routes. This suggests there is perhaps some conflict there?

Comment: I've run into issues similar to this before and solved them by using the index route. In your case, `photos.index` should be the route in which you list your photos - not the `photos` route as you appear to have currently.

Comment: Thanks, that’s solved the issue, and I’ve answered in below. Would be great to get an up vote on it.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by putting `photos.index` as the base root, and then moving `photos.hbs` into a `photos` folder.

```
App.PhotosIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
  model: ->
    @store.find "photo"
)

App.PhotosApprovedRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
  model: ->
    @store.filter 'photo', approved: true, (photo) ->
      photo.get 'approved'
  renderTemplate: (controller) ->
    @render 'photos/index',
      into: 'application'
      controller: controller
)

App.PhotosDisapprovedRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
  model: ->
    @store.filter 'photo', approved: false, (photo) ->
      not photo.get 'approved'
  renderTemplate: (controller) ->
    @render 'photos/index',
      into: 'application'
      controller: controller
)
```

To get activeClass working, I then needed to link to `photos.index` instead of `photos`. Like this:

```
{{!-- application.hbs --}}

<ul>
  <li>{{#link-to "photos.index" activeClass="selected"}}All photos{{/link-to}}</li>
  <li>{{#link-to "photos.approved" activeClass="selected"}}Approved{{/link-to}}</li>
  <li>{{#link-to "photos.disapproved" activeClass="selected"}}Disapproved{{/link-to}}</li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps anyone running into the same issue!

Comment: Glad you got that working, I was just going to suggest the same thing. As a general rule of thumb, resource routes shouldn't do much except set things up for their child routes. I try to keep most of my logic out of them.